# Spring MVC "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No variable named partyId found!" when creating party

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm experiencing a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No variable named partyId found!" error when I try to create a new party using a POST request in my Spring MVC application.

The request body only includes the "partyName" field, but I suspect the "partyId" might also be required. I've checked my controller and service code, but I can't find where the "partyId" is expected or used.

POST request body

```
{
  "partyName": "Zaso"
}
```

My Class

```
package app.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parties")
public class Party {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "party_name")
    private String partyName;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    public Party() {
    }

    public Party(Long id, String partyName, LocalDateTime createdAt, LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.partyName = partyName;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPartyName() {
        return partyName;
    }

    public void setPartyName(String partyName) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Party party)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), party.getId())
                && Objects.equals(getPartyName(), party.getPartyName())
                && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), party.getCreatedAt())
                && Objects.equals(getUpdatedAt(), party.getUpdatedAt());
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(),
                getPartyName(),
                getCreatedAt(),
                getUpdatedAt());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Party{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", partyName=" + partyName +
                ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

my DTO

```
package app.dto;

import app.model.Party;
/**
 * DTO for {@link Party}
 */
public class PartyDto{
    private Long id;
    private String partyName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPartyName() {
        return partyName;
    }

    public void setPartyName(String partyName) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/parties")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<PartyDto>> newParty (@RequestBody PartyDto partyDto){
        Party partyRequest = modelMapper.map(partyDto, Party.class);
        Party newParty = partyService.createParty(partyRequest);

        EntityModel<PartyDto> partyEntityModel = toModel(modelMapper.map(newParty, PartyDto.class));

        return ResponseEntity.created(partyEntityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri())
                .body(partyEntityModel);
    }
```

My Service method:

```
 public Party createParty(final Party partyRequest){
        return partyRepository.save(partyRequest);
    }
```

Logs:

```
INFO com.example.PartyService - Creating new party with name: Zaso
ERROR com.example.PartyController - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No variable named partyId found!
```

What I'm asking:

What could be causing the "No variable named partyId found!" error?
Where should I look for the missing "partyId" assignment?
Are there any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?

I've checked the controller code, but I can't see where the "partyId" is explicitly set. I suspect there might be an issue with the ModelMapper configuration or the mapping between the DTO and the entity class.

Comment: If you rename `id` to `partyId` in `PartyDto` it will work I think also you have to create a constructor in this dto